# strike on the uilabel disappears in uitableview did select cell

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel, uitableview

1)i want to create a striked  text so i have used thet ext frame and i have created it and keep on the lbal it works fine when i have used it in the table cell  when i am selecting the cell the strike on the label disaperared

```
#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

#pragma mark TableView delegate method.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView1
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return 4;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 120;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    tableView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell=nil;

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;     
        //cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      //  cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"strip_11C.png"]];
        //cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"strip_11C_h.png"]];

        UILabel *price1_lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,80,100,26)];
        price1_lbl.text = @"label";
        price1_lbl.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        price1_lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:(13.0)];
        price1_lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        NSString *string =price1_lbl.text;
        CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:price1_lbl.font];
        CGRect buttonFrame = price1_lbl.frame;
        CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(buttonFrame.origin.x , 
                                       4+buttonFrame.origin.y + stringSize.height/2, 
                                       stringSize.width, 1);

        UILabel *lineLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        lineLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:price1_lbl];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lineLabel]; 
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    secondviewcontroller *obj=[[secondviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: here i haven taken as background color for the label. how can we create a strike type text that should be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the strikethrough line directly to the label with the text (price1_lbl). If that doesn't work you may want to give [this lib](https://gist.github.com/1054706) a try.

---

**UPDATE:**

You can use this code:

```
CGSize size = [price1_lbl.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
UILabel *line = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 , label.frame.size.height / 2, size.width, 1)];
line.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[price1_lbl addSubview:line];
```

Comment: Hoe to add it  with the text mr.luders sir

Comment: [price1_lbl addSubview: lineLabel]; But be sure to set the frame of the line label correctly to: origin.x = 0.0f ; origin.y = price1._lbl.frame.size.height / 2.0f ; size.width = price1._lbl.frame.size.width ; size.height = 1.0f

Comment: here i am tacking as the background color . how can i make correctly on xact text sir pls..

Comment: here i am taking as the background color . how can i make correctly on xact text sir pls.. i am not adding line it is background color of the label

Comment: You can't set a strikethrough text explicitly an a UILabel. You have to do it with a workaround... Sorry if I don't really understand you question

Comment: Sir i want to get a srike through on a label is there any better way except adding that class please help me sir to get rid

Comment: There is no way. Use a custom class like the link I provided (or build your own) or (the easiest way) add a UILabel with backgroundcolor and 1px height.

Comment: ok sir it is working by adding that class thank u... can u plese help me on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295242/createpdfcontextcgrectinmediabox-pathcfstringref

Comment: when we did select the row it is getting disappeared sir  the label